# UnityWebRequest and Azure Bot issue

Tags: c#, azure, http, unity-game-engine, botframework

I am currently trying to link a Unity application to my bot messaging endpoint in portal Azure. To do this, I use a UnityWebRequest.GET call as explained in Unity doc (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTextBinaryData.html).

The fact is that I always encounter the same issue when I launch the app: `The HTTP 'GET' method is not supported by the 'GenericJsonWebHookReceiver' WebHook receiver`

I have no idea of how or where do I have to make changes in order to solve this. Does anyone facing the same issue?

Here is my code:

```
IEnumerator GetText()
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("<messaging endpoint of the bot>");
    yield return www.Send();

    if (www.isError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        // Show results as text
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

        // Or retrieve results as binary data
        byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing doesn't have anything to do with **Unity**, but https://[YourBotId].azurewebsites.net/api/messages is not callable via **Get**, it is a **Post** method.  If you navigate to the /api/messages path in a browser, you'll see the same error message.

[image]

Have you tried Posting an Activity to the messages endpoint?

I haven't tried this out, but maybe it can help you: https://github.com/tompaana/bot-direct-line-for-unity

Comment: Thank you for the help, these details were very fuzzy to me. Unfortunately I am facing issues while trying to implement the GitHub link to my project.
I have found another way to perform the skill that I want but I don't know how to add NuGet package from the portal Azure Console online : Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: If your bot was created using the Azure Bot Service, you can edit the project.json in kudi to add nuget packages.   https://[YourSiteName].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell then navigate to site/wwwroot/messages/ then edit project.json and add nuget packages.